# How to have the border in a div appear only if Webpart zone has a webpart in it>

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a webpart wrapped in a div that has a border applied to it (class="wpz-1"). The border appears on the page regardless if the webpart zone has a webpart in it or not. How can I make the border appear only if the webpart zone has a webpart in it?

```
<div class="wpz-1">
    <div data-name="WebPartZone">
        <!--CS: Web Part-->
        <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
        <div xmlns:ie="ie">
            <!--MS:<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" AllowPersonalization="false" ID="x8600600cbb2046468f9615155e5fd921" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" Orientation="Vertical" >-->
                <!--MS:<ZoneTemplate>-->
                    <!--DC: - Web Part  -->
                <!--ME:</ZoneTemplate>-->
            <!--ME:</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>-->
        </div>
        <!--CE: Web Part-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the div attribute based on child elements of your zone(if no webpart in webpart zone, it will not display based on my testing, so check the webpart zone to confirm whether there is webpart inside `<div customAttr="customAttr"`).

Just demo:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<style>
.wpz-1{
    border:1px fuchsia groove;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            if ($('div.ms-webpart-zone', 'div[customAttr="customAttr"]').length < 1) {
                $('div.wpz-1').removeClass("wpz-1");
            }
        })        
    </script>

<WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager runat="server" id="spproxywebpartmanager"></WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager>
<p></p>
<div class="wpz-1">
    <div data-name="WebPartZone">
        <div customAttr="customAttr" xmlns:ie="ie">
            <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" AllowPersonalization="false" ID="x8600600cbb2046468f9615155e5fd921" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" Orientation="Vertical" >                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            <ZoneTemplate>
                    <!--DC: - Web Part  -->
                </ZoneTemplate>
            </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: The code works perfectly but I need the border to disappear when there is no webpart in the webpart zone. Your code makes it disappear all together. Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Just demo, better to test in your scenario to compare the difference(the logic used in JS) when there is webpart and no webpart.